# Mongodb update query matching criteria restriction

Tags: mongodb

Is there any max limit/restriction for matching criteria in Mongodb for the update query?  can i pass more than 1000/2000 "_id" in an array to update them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MongoDB documentation (there no any mentions about it), there no any limitations for the query length. Looks like that it more depends on  the MongoDB client / [language driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/). For example, the MongoDB shell has the [4096 bytes limit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/linenoise.cpp#L143).

Comment: Thanks for your update. I 'll try to pass >1000 parameters.